# I want to run a commmand on all the files in the input folder and get the results in an output folder

Tags: command-line, sound, python, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run a code for YOLO object detection https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

I can run the command and get the desired result for individual video file but I don't want to do it separately for each file

For example:

My command: `python3 yolo_video.py --input sample1.avi --output sample1out.avi --yolo yolo-coco`

But I want something like this
`python3 yolo_video.py --input inputVideos/sample1.avi --output outputVideos/sample1out.avi --yolo yolo-coco`

So the command runs on all the files in the input folder(sample1.avi, sample2.avi, sample3.avi...) and gives the results as files in the output folder (sample1out.avi, sample2out.avi, sample3out.avi...)

Comment: Why not use a `for ... do` loop in bash?

Comment: @vanadium I thought of doing the same but I needed help with that since I'm very new to this. Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the other answer and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a oneliner with semicolons, but best is probably just to make a tiny script or function, and run it with that.

```sh
mkdir -p output_videos
for i in input_videos/* ; do
    [ -f "${i}" ] || continue
    name=$(echo "${i}" | sed 's,.*/\(.*\)\.\(.*\),output_videos/\1out.\2,g')
    python3 yolo_video.py --input "${i}" --output "${name}" --yolo yolo-coco
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I modified the name according to my default video name and it works perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you consider the question answered, please mark it as the answer.